# T4 template error 92

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, t4

In our project, we have templates to generate our model and view model code based on our current database structure. When running T4 against our latest structure which includes a new child table, I get the following exception:

```
Error   92  Running transformation: System.ApplicationException: NewTable
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplatingECF6FDB0BE0E092F4B1ED6433CC6C4D7630B8C2B7B8F2EFB2A673385286B7D5B4A7BB3DAEA910C0E18BC6B730B2BD70049143F2440E3F89B8F48BFA7FA45E47C.GeneratedTextTransformation.TransformText() Generator.tt    1   1
```

I'm having trouble finding what error code 92 refers to, and there doesn't seem to be much of anything else to go on with that exception message.

Has anyone else ever encountered this exception during a transformation?

Answer (score 0):

Long story short, there was a change I needed to make prior to running T4 that I hadn't included. Everything is fine now.

Comment: Was that change related to T4? If so, could you edit the solution in your post?

Comment: The change wasn't related to T4 itself. It had to do with an XML file that feeds the transformation.